# 50 amp breaker for Range on a 60 amp sub panel

Tags: subpanel

I have s 60 amp sub panel that powers only 3 20 amp circuits. Can I add a 50 amp breaker for my range?

Comment: What do those 20A circuits feed?

Comment: Microwave, disposal, refer

Comment: Can you post a photo of the subpanel in question?

Comment: New install. Going to be coming off of a 125 amp main panel..

Comment: What make and model of subpanel are you installing here, and what are you running for a feeder?

Comment: What ThreePhaseEel is getting at is that you have not provided enough information. For example if you have a 40A feeder and #8 wire going to that sub panel, you cannot add a 50A branch to it. Details matter.